# how to make json work in a jsp page using tomcat server?

Tags: json, jsp, tomcat

I have downloaded json library , and my jsp pages are in tomcat/webapps/star/index.jsp .

So where should I extract the json libraries so that the json code contained in index.jsp works ?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, 3rd party libraries in JAR flavor should go in `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib` folder. This folder is taken in the webapp's default runtime classpath. If you'd like to share the same libs among multiple webapplications on the same server, then rather drop it in `Tomcat/lib` folder.

---

By the way, such JSON libraries only converts Java objects to JSON strings and vice versa. They have completely nothing to do with JSON in the JSP side. It's JavaScript who's responsible for that part.

Comment: the problem is I am using Tomcat in ubuntu . And there is no such folder called WEB-INF or Tomcat/lib . what should be done ? If I create a folder , should I extract all the files or keep them in jar format?

Comment: The `Webapp` just stands for *your* webapp. In your case it's named `star`. The `Tomcat` just stands for Tomcat installation folder. And yes, definitely keep it in JAR format.

Comment: still not working . i made a folder in star and extracted json there but it didnt work .

Comment: You should not extract the JAR. If you have loose classes, then they should in fact go in `Webapp/WEB-INF/classes` folder. But if you have a JAR, you should place it unextracted in `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib` folder. I'd suggest to get yourself through a basic JSP/Servlet book to learn the basic concepts.

Comment: i exactly did what you had said and also referred a few examples , the code was like this <%@ page language="java" import="net.sf.json.JSONArray" %>

Comment: Do  I need to make changes to that ?